# Formik input name is not an identifier

Tags: typescript, formik

In typescript-Formik form input are connected by names to variables. But what if a input is inserted by script, which name is not an Identifier. We have this problem with cloudflare Turnstile. There is a input inserted with the name "xxx-turnstile"

```
interface Values {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   email: string;
   xxx-turnstile: string; // syntax error
 }
```

how can I handle this?
Thanks

Comment: I would not recommend to name your property with a dash. But anyway, try `'xxx-turnstile': string;` And then `const values: Values = { "xxx-turnstile": 'foo', ... };` and `console.log(values['xxx-turnstile']);` - not that handy.